# Upgrading to "Snow Leopard" a good Idea for older iBooks?

Tags: macos

I have a MacBook Pro 2.6 Gig Intel Core Duo, 4GB RAM, running OS 10.5.7. I am not worried about that when upgrading to Snow Leopard. I am not even sure if I will do the upgrade...

But I also have an "old" iBook 1.2 Ghz, 700MB RAM that used to be running 10.4. Now I read that the new OS "Snow Leopard" is basically a more efficient "Leopard". At least the disk footprint seems to be 9 Gigs less than before.

Now I wonder if it also runs more efficiently on older hardware...

I kind of need to know this from a hardware point of view. Does anyone have news about this yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Snow Leopard is for Intel based Macs only. Check the [system requirements from Apple](http://www.apple.com/macosx/specs.html).

I believe that your iBook simply won't run it, because it's not an intel processor.

Comment: Well, I already upgraded to 10.5.6 and it is up and running. My iBooks specs are such: PowerPC G4 (1.2), RAM: 768MB. So I am not sure I this is quite right?

Comment: I checked your link and it seems you are right. You must have meant to say "Snow Leopard", I guess. Thanks!

Comment: Since you have a PowerPC processor, Snow Leopard wont' work on your iBook. It needs to have an Intel chip in order to run Snow Leopard.

Comment: i have my old iBook too, and I was thinking to convert it to leopard or snow leopard but i'm afraid it'll run slow and it's already running not so fast :(

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Dan. Silly me - yes, I meant to say Snow Leopard.